# How to parse plists in Python?

Tags: python, plist, typeerror, plistlib

I'm trying to parse through a massive file for an iTunes library and I'm attempting to use [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html#module-plistlib) library.

My code looks something like this:

```
import plistlib

with open('iTunes Music Library.xml') as fp:
    pl = plistlib.load(fp)

print(pl["aKey"])
```

As I do so, I get the error:

> `TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes`

I'm not sure what this is, any explanations?

Comment: What version of Python, and what version of iTunes?

Comment: @davedwards Only in Python 2. Since the OP is using 3.x-style `print`s, and it's 2018, he's more likely to be using 3.x.

Comment: @davedwards that is a previous version, it mentions it on a page that it is outdated, and while I run it.

Comment: Okay, good points, thanks.

Comment: As a side note, historically, `plistlib` has added a lot of overhead over Expat, and also a lot of brittleness, so using it to parse iTunes library files is they're actually massive (as in hundreds of MB) was not really doable; you had to build something on top of, e.g, `etree` instead. I haven't really tried it with the new 3.4+ `plistlib` implementation, so maybe everything will work great… but keep your fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html), `plistlib.load` takes a **binary** file object. You've given it a file opened in text mode.

Comment: Ah, so fixing it would be me changing what the open with is?

Comment: Pass `'rb'` instead of `'r'` (or nothing) as the second argument to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file as a binary, i.e.

```
with open('iTunes Music Library.plist', 'rb') as fp:
        pl = plistlib.load(fp)
```

Comment: How do I print TabURL Value?